# Showing $\sigma$-additivity and a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Let $F: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  increasing and left-continous.

$\mu([a,b)):= F(b)-F(a) \quad$and  $\quad \mathbb I := \{[a,b) | \quad a,b \in \mathbb R , a \leq b \}$.

1) Show that $\mu(\overset{.}{\cup}A_i) = \sum_{i} \mu(A_i)$ for disjointed $A_i \in \mathbb I$

I am not sure if $\mu([a_1,b_1) \overset{.}{\cup} [a_2,b_2)) = F(b_1)-F(a_1) + F(b_2)-F(a_2)$ because $\mu$ isnt defined for unions which is confusing me.

Then I tried to let $A_k = [a_k,b_k) $ and then search for the $\min\{a_k,b_k\}= b_l$ and $\max\{a_k,b_k\}=a_j$ to get the biggest interval possible of the unions over $A_i$, so that $$\mu(\overset{.}{\cup}A_i) = F(a_j)-F(b_l) = ...$$ but that doesnt seem to be the right way.

2) Is it always possible to extend $\mu$ to a measure on the borel set of $\mathbb R$ ?

Totally clueless here

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need a definition for 1).

Comment: @copper.hat what do u mean?

Comment: How do you define $\mu$ for sets other than $[a,b)$?

Comment: @copper.hat $\mu$ is only defined for that Half-Closed Interval. Thats why i am having that much trouble

Comment: Well $\mu([0,2)\cup [1,3))=\mu([0,3))=3 \not = \mu([0,2)) + \mu([1,3))= 2+2=4$, If $F$ is identity. So at least you are missing the assumption that each $A_i$ is disjoint.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen "Show that $\mu(\overset{.}{\cup}A_i) = \sum_{i} \mu(A_i)$ " The $A_i$ are disjoint sorry if it wasnt clear enough by the dot over the cupsymbol

Comment: Well that’s not super common. And also couldn’t see it on my phone..

Comment: @HartoSaarinen All good. Do u have any idea on how to show the equality maybe?

Comment: I missed the dot on first reading.

Comment: One can define $\mu$ for finite unions of disjoint half intervals  using @HartoSaarinen's trick above, but this is an extension of what you have above.

Comment: How do you show that the Lebesgue measure is countably additive? Try to do that first and look if the same argument goes trough.

Comment: I really think you need more information here. One fairly standard route is to define an outer measure using $\mu$ and proceed from there. But until you define $\mu$ on sets other than half intervals not progress is possible here in my opinion.